# Django - Cant set date in field

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I have current code:

```
# ...
from django.utils import timezone


class Order(models.Model):
    # ...
    pay_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    # ...

    def pay(self):
        # ...
        self.pay_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

And i call `pay` method in transaction block:

```
# in one view func.
with transaction.atomic():
    # ...
    order.pay()
```

And after - nothing happened, `pay_date` field still `None`.

I tried set `pay_date` field directly from console, and it worked.

**UPD:**

I also tried to set date in `pre_save` signal, and it still isn't working(state changed, btw):

```
@reciever(pre_save, sender=Order)
def set_pay_date(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # check the special condition
    old_order = Order.objects.get(id=instance.pk)
    if old_order.state == States.NEW and instance.state == States.PAID:
        instance.pay_date = timezone.now()
```

Comment: Are all model constraints met? If not, the transaction will revert all changes.

Comment: Does that view func get called? Does your breakpoint get hit? How do you determine the field is still none?

Comment: @ElwinArens yep, it actually fully working(except setting `pay_date` field ofc), and `pay_date` its a new field, and i added new code in `pay` method for set this field.

Comment: Have you run makemigrations/migrate?

Comment: @Sayse yes, yes, saw in model instance.

Comment: @ElwinArens yes, and i can set this field through console.

Comment: Are you looking in the right database/model instance?... Its not clear how the code you've shown here wouldn't work

Comment: @Sayse yep, in the right instance, i can't understand why such a simple operation isn't working.

Comment: Could you update the code samples to include the entire model, view and any signal listeners?

Comment: @ElwinArens add signal code